# How to obtain the analytical solution of the equation？

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the following equation, and I want to get its analytical solution, but mathematica still can't give its analytical solution. Is there any way to make it give an analytical solution?

```
M = 1; Q = 0.7; a = 0.6; \[Alpha] = 0.9; l0 = 0.2;
Solve[r^2 - 2 M r - \[Alpha] l0 r + Q^2 - \[Alpha] M r Exp[-r/M] + 
   a^2 == 0, r]
```

Or is there any way to obtain its approximate analytical solution?

Comment: Few equations in mathematics have analytical solutions.

Comment: Is the result of `Solve[r^2 - 2 M r - \[Alpha] l0 r + Q^2 - \[Alpha] M r Exp[-r/M] + a^2 == 0, r, Reals]` satisfactory? (Tip: For exact solvers like `Solve`, it is usually better to use exact input. Floating-point numbers are treated as approximate. Numerical solvers like `NSolve` or `FindRoot` may be better choices if approximate results are desired or satisfactory.)

Comment: Alternatively, one can find solutions in a bounded rectangle in $\Bbb C$ like this: `NSolve[r^2 - 2 M r - \[Alpha] l0 r + Q^2 - \[Alpha] M r Exp[-r/M] + a^2 == 0 && -20 < Im[r] < 20 && -10 < Re[r] < 10, r]`.  It appears there may be infinitely many solutions without periodicity or other pattern that allows *Mma* to express the complete solution. Or: `Solve[Rationalize[
   2 M r - \[Alpha] l0 r + Q^2 - \[Alpha] M r Exp[-r/M] + a^2 == 
    0] && -20 < Im[r] < 20 && -10 < Re[r] < 10, r]` for exact `Root[]` objects.

Comment: I think no chance.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

M = 1; Q = 7/10; a = 3/5; α = 9/10; l0 = 1/5;
```

Restrict the domain to [`Reals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reals.html)

```
eqn = r^2 - 2 M r - α l0 r + Q^2 - α M r Exp[-r/M] + a^2 == 0;

sol = Solve[eqn, r, Reals]
```

[image]

```
Verifying the solutions,

eqn /. sol // FullSimplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

The result is given in terms of [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions. The approximate numeric values are

```
sol // N

(* {{r -> 0.343441}, {r -> 1.86348}} *)
```

Graphically,

```
Plot[Evaluate@eqn[[1]], {r, 0, 2},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[{r, 0} /. sol]}]
```

[image]

Comment: In fact, your `sol` is `{{r -> Root[{-90*#1 + E^#1*(85 - 218*#1 + 100*#1^2) & , 
     0.3434410417590972717226381966222565957320.602059991322722}]}, 
 {r -> Root[{-90*#1 + E^#1*(85 - 218*#1 + 100*#1^2) & , 
     1.8634831470915269008646784833389820068620.30103248076972}]}}`. This is not any analytical solution.

Comment: @user64494 - `Root` is as much of an analytic solution as any other higher transcendental function. The fact that is newer doesn’t make it any less useful.

Comment: The documentation says "`Root` represents an exact number as a solution to an equation `f[x]==0` with additional information specifying which of the roots is intended", no more and no less. Also see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Closed-form+expression&title=Special:Search&ns0=1) for the definition of an analytical expression.

Comment: @user64494 - from your link, “ However, the class of expressions considered to be analytic expressions tends to be wider than that for closed-form expressions. In particular, special functions such as the Bessel functions and the gamma function are usually allowed, and often so are infinite series and continued fractions.” `Root`  is  a newer special function. An exact value is what is required by many.

Comment: -1. " Root is a newer special function" is your personal ungrounded opinion.

Comment: @user64494 For practical purposes, Root objects are about as good as more traditional analytic expressions. So, if your intent is to obstruct the solution of problems, you reject them, while if your intent is to enable the solution of problems you embrace them.

Answer (score 2):

If the smaller solution is what you want, you could develop the exponential into a series like

```
Series[E^(-(r/M)), {r, 0, 3}]
```

Higher order means better precision, but more complicated expressions...
A plot shows the effect of the approximation:

```
M = 1; Q = 0.7; a = 0.6; \[Alpha] = 0.9; l0 = 0.2; 
Plot[{r^2 - 2*M*r - \[Alpha]*l0*r + Q^2 - \[Alpha]*M*r*Exp[-r/M] + 
a^2, a^2 + Q^2 - 2*M*r + r^2 - 
l0*r*\[Alpha] - (1 - r/M + r^2/(2*M^2) - r^3/(6*M^3))*M*
r*\[Alpha]}, {r, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

The equation using the approximation may then be solved analytically:

```
Solve[a^2 + Q^2 - 2*M*r + r^2 - 
l0*r*\[Alpha] - (1 - r/M + r^2/(2*M^2) - r^3/(6*M^3))*M*
r*\[Alpha] == 0, r]
(* lengthy expressions *)
```

As this is of 4th order you get 4 solutions. Here the third gives the zero around 0.34.

Comment: Think of `Series[Exp[-r/M],{r,0,7}]//Normal` instead of your  `Series[Exp[-r/M],{r,0,3}]//Normal`, when there is no analytical solution .

Comment: @user64494 but 4th order is the highest you can solve

Comment: "A plot shows the effect of the approximation" - better no say! In fact, you analytically solve a different equation than in the question.

Comment: @user64494 the plot shows that in the area of interest both equations look similar.